# how to set value field in xpages from dblookup result?

Tags: javascript, xpages, return-value, default-value

I have Xpages with fields: Name & Level

The Name value set from formula: `@Name("[ABBREVIATE]",session.getEffectiveUserName());`

And i want to set field Level using `@DbLookup that query to MasterDB.nsf`

The problem is:
I have put script on default value of the field Level, but it does not work. This is the script:

```
db = new Array(@DbName()[0], 'MasterDB.nsf');
var result = @DbLookup(db, "Person", document1.getItemValueString("Name"), 2);
result
```

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

`document1.getItemValueString("Name")` doesn't work in your case as the item "Name" in document1 is only set after a submit. So, it is "too early" to access the item "Name" in document1.

You could access the value of XPages element "Name" with `getComponent("inputTextName").getValue()` but in your case it is easier to calculate the effective user name again in Level's defaults code:

```
var db = new Array(@DbName()[0], 'MasterDB.nsf');
var username = @Name("[ABBREVIATE]",session.getEffectiveUserName());
var result = @DbLookup(db, "Person", username, 2);
return result;
```

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad it works for you. As you are new to StackOverflow please consider to accept answer like described here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/223607